# I'm getting trouble with my Google map?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest

Here im giving my code for google map view, this is not working if i simulate it will comes Force close error,
        any body healp me ,im giving my log cat details also...

1.gmap activity class

```
    package net.gmaps;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    public class GoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mv = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    }
```

2.main.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                     android:id="@+id/mapView"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:enabled="true"
                     android:clickable="true"
                     android:apiKey="0jEK9Odr895XgKEM5xr-nCr6stwV9dUquFVdsWg"
                     />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

3.android manifest file

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.gmaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".GoogleMapsActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

4.my Logcat details

```
     11-30 12:28:45.996: D/AndroidRuntime(306): Shutting down VM
11-30 12:28:45.996: W/dalvikvm(306): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
11-30 12:28:45.996: E/AndroidRuntime(306): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:209)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:203)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-30 12:28:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 12:28:46.085: I/dalvikvm(306): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
11-30 12:28:46.265: I/dalvikvm(306): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Click on your name and click on your question one by one...if the answer is true for the question that you asked, at the left side of that question you will have something to click and accept that answer as true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android manifest file uses library goes in your aplication tags like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
         <activity ....
         </activity>
</application>
```

And put ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permisions....
On onCreate you must define mapView like this:
`MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);` after setContent

Comment: ya ..i did this things but again force close dude

Comment: I didnt try your code, but i will now and tell you what i can find...do you have something else in your code or is this everything??? Please if you have more code edit your question...

Comment: did you build you project with google api's???   I tried code from above and it works...

Answer (score 0):

Add the following permissions to your application in Android.xml.

- ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line

```
(uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps")
```

**after decleration** of application tab in android manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

set build target as that Google Api

select your right click 
**Project > Properties > Android > Google APis**.

If not available then add it through
**Windows>Android SDK and AVD Manager>New**.